# Comparison of different ways of Upsampling in detection models

Tags: computer-vision, convolution, object-detection

There are various ways to increase the resolution of tensor in `(width, height)` dimensions, frequently used in detection models like `FPN`, `YOLO`, e.t.c :

- Upsampling (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html) - which inserts intermediate points between those from previous layers, and the values in this intermediate points are obtained via bilinear intepolation or polynomial interpolation.
- MaxUnpool (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d.html) - which uses the results from the MaxPool layer in the encoding part of the network - location of the max values.
- Deconvolution with stride > 1

The first strategy seems to copy the information from
the previous layer and transform it in some known in prior way.

Max Unpool works like in a similar way - uses the information from the previous layers, and transforms them in a certain way.

Deconvolution with stride in case it has learnable weights can do the increase of resolution in some priorly unknown way, with the trained weights, and seems to be a more flexible approach, but it increases total computational cost in a certain way.

Which of the aforementioned strategies perfoms better in most of the detection problems?

Comment: all can produce artifacts in the upsampled image. Like other upsampling techniques it depends to a large extend on the actual images (eg types of shapes present, noise, etc..)